# How to find an element of an array by id with Observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I decided to use Observable instead of Http promises.

That is how my Promise service looked:

```
export class MovieService {

    movies: Movie[]
    movie: Movie;
    constructor(private http:Http) { }

   getMovies(): Promise<Movie[]>{

        return this.http.get('http://api.request.com')
            .toPromise()
            .then((res:Response) => res.json()['results'])

    }
    getMovie(id: number): Promise<Movie> {
        return this.getMovies()
            .then(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.id == id));

    }

}
```

First I fetch an array of movies, and than I find a certain movie of the array by id. However when I try to do the same with Observable, I get an error notification on find: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Movie[]'.

Here is what I tried with the Observable service:

```
export class MovieService {

    movies: Movie[];
    movie: Movie;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {

        return this.http.get('http://api.request.com)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json()['results']);
    }

    getMovie(id: number): Observable<Movie> {
        return this.getMovies()
            .subscribe(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.id == id));
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same functionality in my Observable service just like in my Promise service?

Comment: *Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Movie[]* is type error, because TS configuration is wrong. It should have `lib: ['es6']` option.

Comment: You are right. I changed that and it works with the find now. Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suppose you should use `map` method instead of `subscribe` which returns `Subscription` object

```
export class MovieService {
  movies: Movie[];
  movie: Movie;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://api.request.com')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json()['results']);
  }

  getMovie(id: number): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.getMovies()
      .map(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.id == id));
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gxDrjC8pv4VIu49pOeH1?p=preview)**

Comment: I also thought of that, because I have to subscribe, when I call that function from an other component. However it gives the same error with the map.

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the error and/or a stacktrace.

Comment: Basically, I tried what you posted above, and the 'find' still gives the same error.

Comment: @Siri0S there is no stacktrace, I am just not able to call the find method on the movies.  When I hover on find, it says: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Movie[]'.

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the plunker. Everything works as expected. There was a Ts configuration problem as well, as you can see above in the comment section of my question.

Comment: Why we are using `?` in `{{movie?.title}}`

Comment: @lukassz We are using it to avoid exception `cannot read value of undefined` because we are getting data asynchronously

Comment: How can I avoid sending an http.get request every time? Is it good practice to store the result of the http.get in a local variable of type observable<Type[]>. Subsequent searches can be made using the 'id' field in the local variable This local variable can then be synced periodically with the server.