# Searching for a specific item in an Observable array

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am attempting to search an Observable<any[]> for an item with a specific attribute. e.g., for a list of users, find a user with a given user ID. Here's the relevant parts of my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentService } from '../shared/services/content.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument  } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  main: Object;
  users: Observable<any[]>;
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private contentService: ContentService, private firestore: AngularFirestore, ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const pageData = this.route.snapshot.data['main'];
    this.main = this.contentService.pages[pageData];
      this.users = this.firestore.collection('users').valueChanges();
  }

  getOwner(id) {
    return this.users
      .map(users => users.find(user => user.uid.equals(id)));
  }

}
```

You can see I attempted trying [this fix using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495483/how-to-find-an-element-of-an-array-by-id-with-observable-in-angular2), but I get the error that "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'." Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this sintax

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  main: Object;
  users: [];
  }
```

```js
 getOwner(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.users
      .map(users => users.find(user => user.uid.equals(id)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `pipe` function

```js
return this.users.pipe(
      map(users => users.find(user => user.uid.equals(id)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but I'm still having some troubles with getting attributes from the returned Observable. I have details in the comment under @Simon Kazakov's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return the owner, you should do something like this:

```
  getOwner(id) {
    return this.firestore.collection('users').get()
      .map(users => users.find(user => user.uid.equals(id)));
  }
```

If you want an observable, returning the owner, you should do something like this:

```
owner$ = this.firestore.collection('users').valueChanges().pipe(
          map(users => users.find(user => user.uid.equals(id))));
```

And then when you need the values from this observable, subscribe to it:
in the template via async pipe:

```
[owner]="owner$ | async"
```

or in the component class with:

```
owner$.subscribe(o => console.log(o))
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option is mostly working for me! The only thing I'm confused on is the assignment to a variable. For context, I need to find multiple owners, and I am calling the getOwner function in HTML like so (LoggedActivity is another Observable<any[]> that I didn't include in the original question):
`<tr *ngFor="let act of LoggedActivity | async">
          <td>{{getOwner(act.ownerId)}}</td>
 </tr>
`
So how would I get an attribute of the owner, for example displayName after calling getOwner?